# Finding a set of a subgroup in Sx

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations

I cannot think of a set $X$ and a subgroup $H$ of $S_x$ which is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\;\sigma\in S_{\Bbb Z}\;$ be defined by $\;\sigma(n):=n+1\;$ , and now just take $\;\langle\,\sigma\,\rangle\le S_{\Bbb Z}\;$ ...

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Let $X = \Bbb Z$, and recall that $\Bbb Z = \langle 1\rangle$ is the unique (up to isomorphism) infinite cyclic group.